# Return Array of Objects in JSON in django rest_framework

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using Django REST Framework

I am getting below JSON response
**Current JSON**
[
{
"id": 1,
"firstname": "Rakesh",
"laststname": "Maini"
},
{
"id": 2,
"firstname": "Tarun",
"laststname": "Arora"
}
]

**Expected JSON**
{
"Employees": [
"Rakesh",
"Tarun",
]
}

```
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    laststname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    emp_id = models.IntegerField
    def __str__(self):
    return self.firstname
```

```
    class Meta:
        model = employees
        fields= "__all__"
```

```
    # This method will return the data of emploies
    def get(self, request):
        employee = employees.objects.all()
        serializer = employeesSerializer(employee, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get(self, request):
    employee = employees.objects.all()
    employee_first_name = [i.first_name for i in employee]
    result = {"employees": employee_first_name}
    return Response(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to manipulate the data generated by the serializer in order to obtain the expected result.

```
def get(self, request):
    employee = employees.objects.all()
    serializer = employeesSerializer(employee, many=True)

    data = {}
    data["Employees"] = [employee["firstname"] for employee in serializer.data]

    return Response(data=data)
```